How to transform self-defined structure into std::string using std::stringstream?
I want to transform a self-defined structure into a std::string,and it occurs to me to use std::stringstream because it can easily transform various kind of type into std::string.
template<typename T>
std::string type_to_string(const T &in) {
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << in;
    return ss.str();
}

struct st_Key {
    std::string a;
    int b;
    char c;
    ...

    template<typename OStream>
    friend OStream &operator<<(OStream &os, const st_Key &c) {
        // wanted form to output
        return os << "a"
                  << "=[" << c.a<< "]"
                  << "b"
                  << "=[" << c.b<< "]"
                  << "c"
                  << "=[" << c.c<< "]";
    }
};

And how I want to trans to std::string like
std::string s = type_to_string(st_Key{"a", 1, 'c'});

But it has some errors when compiling:
<source>: In instantiation of 'OStream& operator<<(OStream&, const st_Key&) [with OStream = std::__cxx11::basic_stringstream<char>]':
<source>:14:8:   required from 'std::string type_to_string(const T&) [with T = st_Key; std::string = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>]'
<source>:36:35:   required from here
<source>:31:36: error: invalid initialization of reference of type 'std::__cxx11::basic_stringstream<char>&' from expression of type 'std::basic_ostream<char>'
   31 |                   << "=[" << c.c<< "]";
      |                                    ^~~

So what's wrong in it?
https://godbolt.org/z/q6zo8r98s

All of the operator<< functions included in the standard library don't work with the specific stream types directly. Instead, they take a std::basic_ostream<CharT, Traits>& as parameter and use that as the return type as well.
In your operator<<(OStream&, const st_Key&) you're trying to return a std::stringstream&, but the output operators used in the return statement only return the base class. Casting a base class reference back to the derived type is not implicit.
You can do the same as the std functions and use basic_ostream as a type instead of templating for the specific stream type:
template<typename CharT, typename Traits>
friend std::basic_ostream<CharT, Traits> &operator<<(std::basic_ostream<CharT, Traits> &os, const st_Key &c) {
    // wanted form to output
    return os << "a"
              << "=[" << c.a<< "]"
              << "b"
              << "=[" << c.b<< "]"
              << "c"
              << "=[" << c.c<< "]";
}

